# Opencv unable to import in android using the chaquopy

Tags: android, opencv, chaquopy

**Python using chaquopy in android**

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


   def main(imageBytes):
       np_data = np.asarray(imageBytes,np.uint8)
       img = cv2.imdecode(np_data,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


    if img.shape[0] > img.shape[1]:
        img = cv2.transpose(img)

    #img = cv2.resize(img, (1600, 1200))

    return str(str(img.shape[0]) + "_"  + str(img.shape[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install the package](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-requirements) into your app before you can import it. The OpenCV package name is `opencv-python`.